# How to add a popup text with Openstreetmap tag information in OpenLayers 3

Tags: popup, openstreetmap, openlayers-3, overpass-api

I created a map with Openlayers 3 (v3.11.2) with an Openstreetmap Basemap.
I'm loading features from Openstreetmap via the Overpass API.

```js
/** OSM Overpass Layer*/
var osmxmlFormat = new ol.format.OSMXML();

/** Public Transport Layer*/
var osmTransportSource = new ol.source.Vector({
    loader: function(extent, resolution, projection) {
        var url = 'https://overpass-api.de/api/interpreter?data=%5Bout%3Axml%5D%3Barea%283600062422%29%2D%3E%2E' +
        'searchArea%3B%28node%5B%22public%5Ftransport%22%3D%22stop%5Fposition%22%5D%28area%2EsearchArea%29%3B%' +
        '29%3B%28%2E%5F%3B%3E%3B%29%3Bout%20body%3B%0A';
        $.ajax(url).then(function(response) {
            var features = osmxmlFormat.readFeatures(response,
                {featureProjection: projection});
            osmTransportSource.addFeatures(features);
        });
    }
});

var osmTransportVector = new ol.layer.Vector({
    source: osmTransportSource
});
```

Also I'm able to build a popup window that is able to grab information from a feature one is clicking on. But I could only make it work with a GEOJson stored in the same folder as my script.

```js
/**Elements that make up the popup.*/
var container = document.getElementById('popup');
var content = document.getElementById('popup-content');


/**Create an overlay to anchor the popup to the map.*/
var overlay = new ol.Overlay(({
    element: container,
    autoPan: true,
    autoPanAnimation: {
        duration: 250
    }
}));
```

...

```js
/**Add a pointermove handler to the map to render the popup.*/
    map.on('click', function(evt) {
        var coordinate = evt.coordinate;
        var feature = map.forEachFeatureAtPixel(evt.pixel, 
            function(feature, layer) {
                return feature;
            }, null, function(layer) {
                return layer === districtLayer;
            });
        if(feature != undefined){
         content.innerHTML = feature.get('OTEIL'); //OTEIL is the name of a feature propertie in my GEOJson
         overlay.setPosition(coordinate);
         }
    });
```

The question now is: How can I grab the tag information provided in the OSM data. I already saw it on some webpages like this: [pic of popup with OSM tags](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TLyRL.jpg), [link to page](http://maxheight.bplaced.net/overpass/map.html). But I could not undestand their scripts as I'm a beginner in programming and this is my first webpage (and my first question on stackoverflow). 
Therefore - if you answer - please explain in detail what has to be done.